# How to pick the second or third element from array?

Tags: android, arrays

I have a `String[]` with 10 items in it. each item is the text of an edittext. I shuffle the values of the array with `Collections.shuffle(array);`.
 Now I need to print the second item in my textview. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] items = new String[]{"a","b"};
List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(items));
Collections.shuffle(itemList);

TextView txtItem = findViewById(R.id.textView);
txtItem.set(itemList.get(1))
```

Since `Collections.shuffle` receive List as a parameter, you should convert arrays to List.
items[1] is important part to pick element from the array. Since number start from 0, second is 1, third is 2.